# View Model inheritance when using Durandal

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I am building an application using Durandal and I have the need to share some functionality across view models.

I have 5 screens to build and they are all virtually the same screen except that in the activate function they will call to a different api end points but otherwise the view and view models will be identical.

Is there a pattern that I should be following to structure this correctly to promote code reuse?

Comment: I would look at durandal's samples folder and take a look at the masterDetail sample.  I think that might be similar to what your talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the views and the view models are identical except for calling different api actions, what about just taking in a parameter as part of the route?  Then in the activate function, you can switch on the parameter.  The route values can be designated so that your url is relevant, like [http://site/page/subtype], where subtype is the parameter (instead of using numeric values)

Regarding inheritance, depending on the features you need, there's so many ways to do JavaScript inheritance it can be a little confusing.  There are some full-featured inheritance models provided by libraries such as base2 and Prototype.  [John Resig also has an inheritance model](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) that I've used successfully.

In general, I prefer to stick to simpler solutions when it comes to JS inheritance.  If you need a pretty much the full set of inheritance features, those libraries are good to consider.  If you only really care about accessing a set of properties and functions from a base class, you might be able to get by with just defining the view model as a function, and replacing the function's prototype with the desired base class.  Refer to [Mozilla's Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) for good info on inheritance.

Here's a sample:

```
 //viewModelBase
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    function _ctor() {

        var baseProperty = "Hello from base";
        function baseFunction() {
            console.log("Hello from base function");
        }
        //exports
        this.baseProperty = baseProperty;
        this.baseFunction = baseFunction;
    };

    //return an instance of the view model (singleton)
    return new _ctor();
});

//view model that inherits from viewModelBase
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    function _ctor() {

        var property1 = "my property value";
        function activate() {
            //add start up logic here, and return true, false, or a promise()
            return true;
        }
        //exports
        this.activate = activate;
        this.property1 = property1;
    };

    //set the "base"
    var _base = require("viewModelBase");
    _ctor.prototype = _base;
    _ctor.prototype.constructor = _ctor;

    //return an instance of the view model (singleton)
    return new _ctor();
});
```

Keep in mind this example all results in what effectively is a singleton (i.e. you'll only get the same instance, no matter how many times you require() it)

If you want a transient (non-singleton) just return _ctor.  Then you'll need to instantiate a new instance after you require() it.

One more note, in general, functions should be defined on the prototype, not within the constructor function itself.  See [this link for more information on why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659151/91189).  Because this example results in only a single instance, it's a moot point, so the functions are inside the constructor for improved readability and also the ability to access the private vars and functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's a good point. It would get around the scenario I outlined. I'm really interested to know how to achieve inheritance in view models though.

Comment: Edited to include some additional info specifically regarding inheritance.

Comment: Thanks very much @heiserman, really helpful, learnt a lot there. Do you mind posting what viewModelBase would look like?

Comment: no problem.  The more code I added, the more I felt like I'd better test it, so I did.  As a result, there are a couple of tweaks from the original version, but this code does work in a Durandal app.